# Swagger UI doesn't pass content-type for a part within a multipart request

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I am using the following code to configure an ASP.NET Core 3.1 controller method to upload a multipart request with 2 parts, one named "metadata" to contain a JSON model and another part named "file" to contain the actual file binary. The Swagger UI seems to render correctly but when invoking the operation, it never sends the "content-type" for my metadata part.

When debugging my controller method, the part for the file binary is fine and includes the "content-type" header but when I inspect the headers for the metadata part, the "content-type" header is missing. The only header that I receive for the metadata part is "content-disposition".

I did confirm that swagger.json is correctly showing "application/json" as the content-type for the metadata part.

Currently I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.0.0-rc4

Am I missing anything in the operation filter or anything else?

```cs
public class FileUploadOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public virtual void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        context?.MethodInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<FileUploadOperationAttribute>()?.Apply(operation, context);
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class FileUploadOperationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type MetadataType { get; }

    public string MetadataPropertyName { get; set; } = "metadata";

    public string FilePropertyName { get; set; } = "file";

    public FileUploadOperationAttribute(Type metadataType)
    {
        MetadataType = metadataType;
    }

    public virtual void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation == null || context == null)
            return;

        var metadataSchema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(
            MetadataType,
            context.SchemaRepository);

        operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody
        {
            Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
            {
                ["multipart/form-data"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                {
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "object",
                        Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
                        {
                            [MetadataPropertyName] = metadataSchema,
                            [FilePropertyName] = new OpenApiSchema
                            {
                                Type = "string",
                                Format = "binary",
                            },
                        },
                    },

                    Encoding = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiEncoding>
                    {
                        [MetadataPropertyName] = new OpenApiEncoding
                        {
                            ContentType = "application/json",
                        },
                    },
                }
            },
        };
    }

}

[HttpPut("{fileName}/versions/{version}/content")]
[FileUploadOperation(typeof(SubmitFileRequest))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GenericActionResponse), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitFileVersionContentAsync([FromRoute] string fileName, [FromRoute] string version, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // code omitted for brevity...
}

public class SubmitFileRequest
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastWriteTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string InstallMethod { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue with Swagger UI – currently (as of December 2019) it does not add the `Content-Type` header to JSON data within `multipart/*` requests. The issue is tracked here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5356